# How to make an HTML5 that does not require the blackberry browser component?

Tags: html, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I used the latest and greatest jQuery Mobile (RC1) to develop an app for the client. I used the latest Webworks version from RIM and packaged the app in a Cod file.

The app works great if accessed through the web browser ETC however when I installed the actual generated JAD/Cod files onto a blackberry device, performance was horrible even with minimum number of jQuery libraries.

Since I have Googled this everywhere and it is apparent that one cannot have a meaningful app experience if Webworks is used, I want to be able to just create something that just places the app icon on the phone. Once clicked, it open the browser and takes the user to the web server where the HTML files are parked.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that, with a very simple Java-application.

The following code:

```
 Browser.getDefaultSession().displayPage("http://www.yourserver.com");
```

It will open browser and open page: http://www.yourserver.com

Browser class javadoc is here: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/browser/Browser.html